# rsync error script

Tags: ssh, backup, rsync

I wrote a small script for rsync which does not work and I have no idea why:

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync  \
-a \
--delete \
-b --backup-dir=/lunarc/nobackup/users/mcocdawc/.MIL53_backup/  \
--checksum \
-Pv  --human-readable \
-e ssh alarik:/lunarc/nobackup/users/mcocdawc/MIL53/ /home/mcocdawc/PowerFolders/Molcas_project/MIL53
```

The error message is:

```
 rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(873) [Receiver=3.1.0]
```

I am running `rsync 3.1.0` on `Ubuntu 14.04` and I am able to connect to the remote computer using `ssh` without any problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script works for me (with the directories changed to directories that exist on my computers); I'm also using `rsync 3.1.0` on `Ubuntu 14.04`.

Note that `--backup-dir` is used to give a backup directory *on the receiving end*, so you probably want `--backup-dir=/home/mcocdawc/PowerFolders/Molcas_project/.MIL53_backup` instead.

Comment: I actually wanted the backup on the sending end, but using it on the receiving end works for me as well. Changing the backup-dir made the script executing. Thank you very much!